# Java return method good practice when filling an object

Tags: java

Sorry for the ambiguous title. I'll edit when if someone has a better way to explain this.

Let's say I have a class that I create many instance of and that has many attributes that get filled by different methods. Is it bad practice to pass the object around and fill the attributes in the methods ? I'll try to explain with an example that I tried to make simple:

```
public class User {
    private String surname;
    private String name;

    public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname( String surname ) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName( String name ) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
// Passing the object as parameter and returning the object in each methods
// In this case getNameFromSomewhere returns a User object

public User getUser(){ //edit: my mistake here
    User user= new User();  

    user = getNameFromSomewhere(user);  
    user = getSurnameFromSomewhere(user);    

    return user;    
}
```

In my case, getNameFromSomewhere does a search on a server, I was wondering if I should change all my methods so it returns  a string just like the attribute and then just do :

```
// Alternative ?
public User getUser(){ //edit: my mistake here
    User user= new User();  

    user.setName(getNameFromSomewhere());   // getNameFromSomewhere  return string 
    user.setName(getSurnameFromSomewhere());    

    return user;    
}
```

*note: I have string, int, list attributes to fill.
edit: I wrote an alternative, I'm simply wondering, performance wise, if it's good to pass a User as parameter and then return it filled with 1 attribute for every attribute or if I should just use the User.set method to fill the attribute and have my methods return the attribute type. (is this a bit more clear?)

Comment: well, sorry but I didn't understand what you're trying to achieve

Comment: Isn't that what you're already doing?

Comment: You should have included the alternative which you (although not we) have in mind.  How else could you have avoided passing the user?

Comment: And why if you're getting a user through a parameter, do you need to do `User user = new User();`? You already have that name being used.

Comment: If the method itself is returning an object of `User` class, then there is no need to instantiate the `User`  reference, inside `getUser(...)` method. Method is taking a parameter, though it is creating a new `User`, but the work of creating a `User` has been delegated to the third function, which itself creates a user. Why `new User()` at every corner, why not let only `User` be created at one place, just use a variable to hold that reference.

Comment: I edited my post to make it clearer, I hope it's better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `User` class exposes its internals through the *setter* methods, breaking the **information hiding** principle. Your approach could lead to an unmaintainable code base, i.e. it will be difficult to trace all the components that could modify a `User` object.

I think a better approach is to have a constructor that takes directly the information needed to build a `User`.

```
public class User {
    private String surname;
    private String name;

    public User(String name, String surname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Then, you can build a user in the following way:

```
public User getUser() {
    User user = new User(getNameFromSomewhere(), 
                         getSurnameFromSomewhere());  
    return user;    
}
```

In this way you're sure where your user came from and that it cannot be modified anywhere else. Moreover, this code is compliant to the **single responsibility principle**, because the methods `getNameFromSomewhere` and `getSurnameFromSomewhere` have the only responsibility to retrieve the name / surname.

The optimal approach should be the one that use an *immutable* implementation of the `User` class. That means that every time you need to modify an object, you create a copy from it with the desired information changed. This way the whole testing process becomes simpler.

Comment: Thank you! This sounds very logical. I agree the way I did things breaks a few principles. I tried changing it but I faced another problem : some methods I use set many attributes of User i.e: 
public User getPersonalInfo(User user) which sets name, surname, email, telephone, etc. from a single ldap search. Is there a good way to follow the principles without using user as parameter and return statement ?

Comment: If you have too many attributes inside `User`, probably it should be splitted into smaller types. As you mentioned in your comment, try to create a `PersonalInfo` type and put this as an attribute inside `User`. So, this way, you can retrieve first the personal infos and than you can build your `User` object.

Comment: If you agree with my answer, please check it as correct. Let me know if you need more help.

Answer (score 2):

yes, it is better to have `getNameFromSomewhere()` return the value instead of having it accept a user Object and call the setter. There are two reasons for that:

1. You want to decouple the interface that User class exposes. so when you refactor surname into familyname, you dont need to change `getNameFromSomewhere()`
2. it is possible that `getNameFromSomewhere()` will be used to fill attribute of some other bean, besides User.

Comment: Do you know if this has an impact performance/memory wise ? Like Am I creating copies that might stay in memory or java garbages everything after use?
I like the second point of your answer. I have some method that searches for 3 attributes at the same time, should I use my method of passing the User and return it then? Or maybe return an array and set the attributes after?

Comment: performance/efficiency-wise there shuld be no difference.  regarding getter that fetches multiple attributes, I would go for three getters that call the same method that does the search and implement some cache mechanism so the actual search gets performed once (assuming the three getters are called fairly close to each other)